# Diferença de tamanho (Release/Debug)

Tags: delphi, debug, release

No Delphi tem *Build Configurations* (Release e Debug), escolhendo o Release o tamanho do executável diminui, queria saber o que ele deixa de incluir no Release, pois o tamanho teve uma diminuição considerável em relação ao Debug.

Comment: A diferença de tamanho deve-se praticamente à parte que a ferramenta de *debug* necessita: execução passo a passo, inspecção do valor de variáveis, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Debug**

É a forma de compilação utilizada para depurar a aplicação.
Ela vai gerar um executável maior por causa disso, porque para debugar algumas coisas, é necessário ter os pontos de referencias do código.

**Release**

É a forma de compilação enxuta, onde é gerado a versão que será disponibilizada para o cliente. Ela é menor pois não precisamos das referencias.

--

Essa é a diferença básica entre as duas, mas você pode customizar individualmente cada uma delas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso vai permitir você fazer validações diferente quando estiver em Release ou Debug utilizando diretivas.

--

Você ainda pode criar suas próprias formas, onde pode adicionar verificações de vazamentos de memória, Code Review, Cobertura e varias outras coisas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom, está esclarecido, mas pode acontecer de algum processo funcionar no Debug e não funcionar do mesmo jeito no Release?... se acontecer teria que adicionar a referência no Release?

Comment: Sim, é possível. Mas vai depender da sua implementação.
Ainda mais se estiver usando as diretivas {$IFNDEF DEBUG} e {$IFNDEF RELEASE}

Comment: Sim, mas então não tenho certeza se o que estou implementando no modo Debug vai funcionar no Release?... pois já aconteceu comigo de eu testar o programa no Debug e no Release ele não fazia o mesmo processo.

Comment: Como eu disse, vai depender da sua implementação, agora, se você não customizou nada, o funcionamento deve ser os mesmo para os dois. A não ser que sua aplicação depende de algum componente externo (dll/so), e esse cara não está presente no lugar definido, pois por default o Delphi gera os executáveis Release/Debug em pastas separadas.

Comment: Certo, obrigado pela ajuda Victor.

Comment: quando vou liberar a versão para o cliente pelo Release, é necessário dar um Clean antes ou só compilar e depois dar um Build?

Comment: Acredito que não precise dar o Clean. o Clean serve para limpar os arquivos gerados, como DCUs, Exes, e por ai vai. O Build sempre vai gerar esses caras e sobrescrever os antigos.

Comment: Tranquilo, o certo então seria compilar e logo depois dar um build?

Comment: O ideal é da rum Build All (Shift + F9)

Comment: Blz, valeu Victor!

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão existem três configurações de compilação: **Base**, **Debug** e **Release**.

No *Project Manager*, *Build Configurations* representa **Base**, as configurações de **Debug** e **Release** estão listados em nós separados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode alterar os valores de opção em qualquer configuração, incluindo **Base**. Você pode excluir as configurações de **Debug** e **Release**, mas não **Base**.

Quando você compilar e salvar um projeto, os arquivos são salvos em um diretório cujo nome corresponde ao nome da configuração de compilação atual. Os diretórios de **Debug** e **Release** existem por padrão, e um diretório é criado para qualquer configuração de compilação personalizada ativa quando você salva um projeto.

- Use a configuração de **Debug** quando o projeto estiver em fase de desenvolvimento, onde é necessário fazer a depuração do projeto.
- Use a configuração de **Release** quando o projeto estiver em fase final de desenvolvimento, a versão que será disponibilizada para o usuário final.

Sobre o **tamanho da aplicação**: isso é devido a configuração de **Debug** ser uma extensão de **Base**, porém sem otimização, assim permitindo fazer depuração, bem como a definição de opções de sintaxe específicas.

A configuração de **Release** também é uma extensão de **Base**, porém não produz [informações de depuração simbólicas](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Debug_information_(Delphi)), o código não é gerado para que seja feito chamadas de [`TRACE`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Trace_Into) e [`ASSERT`](https://delphicleancode.wordpress.com/2016/04/11/delphi-assertions/), e isso faz com que o tamanho do executável ser reduzido.

Veja abaixo um comparativo entre as duas configurações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>[**Imagem original aqui**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoIYC.png)</sub>

Fontes: [`1`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Build_Configurations_Overview), [`2`](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/ss/debug-vs-release-in-delphi-build-configurations.htm)